# Play Framework Does Not Create Models

Tags: java, playframework

I just downloaded the play framework from their site and am working through [this tutorial](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaTodoList).

I've noticed the framework creates the folders app/controllers and app/views, but not a models folder. I created it manually and added Task.java to it.  When I get to the section entitled "Rendering the first page" and open `localhost:9000/tasks` I get a compilation error that says `package play.models does not exist`.  Here is what my Task.java looks like:

```
package models;
import java.util.*;

public class Task {
    public Long id;
    @Required
    public String label;

    public static List<Task> all() {
        return new ArrayList<Task>();
    }

    public static void create(Task task) {
    }

    public static void delete(Long id) {
    }
}
```

Here is application.java, the file generating the compilation error:

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;
import play.data.*;  
import play.models.*;    // COMPILATION ERROR: "package play.models does not exist"!

public class Application extends Controller {
static Form<Task> taskForm = Form.form(Task.class);

public static Result index() {
    //return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    return redirect(routes.Application.tasks());
}

public static Result tasks() {
    return ok(views.html.index.render(Task.all(), taskForm));
}

public static Result newTask() {
    return TODO;
}

public static Result deleteTask(Long id) {
    return TODO;
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's supposed to be `import models.Task;` as opposed to `import play.models.*;`

Answer (score 0):

That's quite confusing (IMHO) step in this tutorial, instead scroll down to `Persist the tasks in a database` section which describes preparing a model to cooperate with DB :) (it extends `Model` class, uses proper annotations, etc)

As you recognized it yet, you need to create a `models` package yourself.

Also as **cYn** wrote: you should import models like `models.SomeModel` into your controller

Answer (score 0):

You are correct HukeLau_DABA , the Play will not create the models package for you. you have to create it.
I got these imports in my Application controller class. I got this sample play application running.

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._
import models.Task
```

and another thing in Eclipse is it will not import the necessary imports automatically.
it is bit pain now, once the IDE support get better I hope this will change.

Comment: what are those underscores?  I typed those in and got a compilation error.

Comment: its wild card similar to * in Java

Comment: Hi what happend, is it working or not, if you got the answer from here please accept one of the answers.